# How to pass multiple value parameter to reporting services report via powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I can pass single value parameters to reporting services without any problems.  However I cannot figure out how to send a multiple value string parameter to the report.  In my report a field named "multival" is set to "Allow multiple values".  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251753(v=vs.90).aspx) states to pass in string[] for multiple values.  I just cannot get the syntax to work for this in PowerShell.  Some example code is below.

```
$multiVal = @('item1','item2','item5','item7');

....

$params[0] = new-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("multival", $multiVal, $false);
```

I've spent quite a bit of time searching the internet and cannot find any PowerShell specific examples of how to accomplish this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE #1**

Below is a more complete sample and the full output of the error message.

```
# Function to save each report as a PDF file
function Generate-Report
{
    Param ($param1, $param2, $param3, $startdate, $enddate)

    # Create a report viewer
    $rv = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer;
    $rv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = "http://myserver/reportserver";
    $rv.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Folder/Folder/Report";
    $rv.ProcessingMode = [Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode]::Remote;     
    $rv.ShowParameterPrompts = $false;

    # Need these variables for PDF rendering
    $deviceInfo = $null;
    $mimeType = $null;
    $encoding = $null;
    $extension = $null;
    $streamids = $null;
    $warnings = $null;

    $multival = @('item1','item2','item4','item5','item8','item10'); # This does not work
    #$multival = @('item1');  # This works

    # Set Parameters
    $params = $null;
    $params = New-Object 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]' 5
    $params[0] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("startdate", $startdate, $false);
    $params[1] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("enddate", $enddate, $false);
    $params[2] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("param1", $param1, $false);
    $params[3] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("param3", $param3, $false);
    $params[4] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("multival", $multival, $false);

    $rv.ServerReport.SetParameters($params);
    $rv.ServerReport.Refresh();

    # Render the report as PDF
    $bytes = $null; 
    $bytes = $rv.ServerReport.Render("PDF", $deviceInfo, 
                [ref] $mimeType, 
                [ref] $encoding, 
                [ref] $extension, 
                [ref] $streamids, 
                [ref] $warnings);

    # Save the PDF file to the designated location
    $file = "$outputFolder\$param1 - $param2.pdf";
    $fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($file, [IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::None)
    $fileStream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    $fileStream.Close();
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
Exception calling "Render" with "7" argument(s): "This report requires a default or 
user-define value for the report parameter 'multival'. To run or subscribe to this 
report, you must provide a parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet)"
At C:\MyScript.ps1:85 char:37
+     $bytes = $rv.ServerReport.Render <<<< ("PDF", $deviceInfo,
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Write" with "3" argument(s): "Buffer cannot be null. Parameter 
name: array"
At C:\MyScript.ps1:95 char:22
+     $fileStream.Write <<<< ($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

**UPDATE #2**

As pointed out in the comments I needed to declare $multival as a StringCollection.  Once I did that the code worked.  See updated snippet below.

```
$multival = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$ret = $multival.Add('item1')
$ret = $multival.Add('item2')
$ret = $multival.Add('item4')
$ret = $multival.Add('item5')
$ret = $multival.Add('item8')
$ret = $multival.Add('item10')
```

Comment: string[] simply means an array of strings. Just pass something like this: ('item', 'item2'). Actually you're doing that - I don't see why your example wouldn't work.

Comment: @Swonkie - Yes I agree and have tried that but it just doesn't like it.  If I pass in ('item1') that works without issue.  However ('item1', 'item2') will not work and I get rsReportParameterValueNotSet on "multival". - Just saw your edited comment.  Thank you for trying.

Comment: Well, this works for me: New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("multival", ('foo', 'bar'), $false)  It's not the command, something else must be wrong on your environment.

Comment: @Swonkie - Thank you.  I'll research the rest of my code some more.  It just through me off when I saw that ('item1') would work.

Comment: Try splatting the array: `ReportParameter("multival', @multival, $false)`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - That does not work.  I get the following error: "The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression."

Comment: Have you tried forcing $multival to be a String[], either by declaring it as such or casting it. That might explain why @Swonkie's example works...

Comment: @Stephen - Yes I have tried putting a [String[]] before the $multival variable to force it.  Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: According to MSDN the ReportParameter.Values property is of type  [StringCollection]. My guess is that it can't easily cast the [String[]] into a [StringCollection]. See this article for managing [StringCollection] objects from Sharepoint PS API http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/22/use-powershell-to-manage-lists-views-and-items-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: @Stephen - That was to solution!  Thank you so much.  If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it.  In the mean time I'll add an update showing the modified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN the ReportParameter.Values property is of type [StringCollection]. PowerShell can't easily cast the [String[]] into a [StringCollection]. See [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/22/use-powershell-to-manage-lists-views-and-items-in-sharepoint.aspx) article for an example of how to use [StringCollection] objects within PowerShell